# How do I decrypt a private key file and sign some text using openssl calls in C?

Tags: c, cryptography, openssl

I have 2 separate programs (spliced together below). The first generates the key pair and saves to files (works fine). The second opens the private key, decrypting with a pass phrase and then I need it to sign a string of text. The code below fails on the PEM_read_PrivateKey() (last) call (can't see why). Can anyone point me at what I am doing wrong and then what openssl calls I should make to use the private key to sign some text?

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *priv_pem = "priv.pem";
    char *pub_pem  = "pub.pem";
    char *pass     = "Password";
    FILE *fp;   
    int bits = 4096;
    unsigned long exp = RSA_F4;

    RSA *rsa;
    EVP_PKEY *pkey;

    //  GENERATE KEY
    rsa=RSA_generate_key(bits,exp,NULL,NULL);
    if (RSA_check_key(rsa)!=1)
        Exit(1,"Error whilst checking key","");
    pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
    EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pkey, rsa);

    //  WRITE ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY
    if (!(fp = fopen(priv_pem, "w")))
        Exit(2,"Error opening PEM file",priv_pem);
    if (!PEM_write_PrivateKey(fp,pkey,EVP_aes_256_cbc(),NULL,0,NULL,pass))
        Exit(3,"Error writing PEM file",priv_pem);
    fclose(fp);

    //  WRITE PUBLIC KEY
    if (!(fp = fopen(pub_pem, "w")))
        Exit(4,"Error opening PEM file",pub_pem);
    if (!PEM_write_PUBKEY(fp, pkey))
        Exit(5,"Error writing PEM file",pub_pem);
    fclose(fp);
    // ------- End of key generation program -------

    // ------- Start of text signing program -------
    //  READ IN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY
    if (!(fp = fopen(priv_pem, "r")))
        Exit(6,"Error reading encrypted private key file",priv_pem);
    if (!PEM_read_PrivateKey(fp,&pkey,NULL,pass))
        Exit(7,"Error decrypting private key file",priv_pem);
    fclose(fp);

    // Sign some text using the private key....

    //  FREE
    RSA_free(rsa);  
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you initialised `pkey` to `NULL` before you pass `&pkey` to `PEM_read_PrivateKey()`? If not, it will attempt to re-use the `EVP_PKEY` structure that `pkey` points to - and if `pkey` is uninitialised, it will be looking at a random spot in memory.

You can use `ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);` to dump the OpenSSL error stack to `stderr` when an error occurs - this is often helpful in finding the problem.

Comment: I added pkey = NULL; prior to PEM_read_PrivateKey(). It still errors and ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr); shows:

Comment: 2732:error:0906B072:lib(9):func(107):reason(114):.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:481:

Comment: I've just looked at pem.lib and the error is taking place in PEM_get_EVP_CIPHER_INFO which is barfing because it doesn't know what the EVP_CIPHER is. How do I associate the EVP_aes_256_cbc() cipher before the PEM_read_PrivateKey() call?

Comment: @Steve: That appears to be an "unsupported algorithm" error.  You should be using `PEM_write_PKCS8PrivateKey()` to write the key - `PEM_write_PrivateKey()` is deprecated, and this *might* be the problem (trying to use the old format with AES 256?)

Comment: @caf: I changed the call to PEM_write_PKCS8PrivateKey(same args) and it now errors on that call  with: 732:error:06074079:lib(6):func(116):reason(121):.\crypto\evp\evp_pbe.c:89:TYPE=PBES2
732:error:23077073:lib(35):func(119):reason(115):.\crypto\pkcs12\p12_decr.c:83:
732:error:2306C067:lib(35):func(108):reason(103):.\crypto\pkcs12\p12_decr.c:168:
732:error:2307D067:lib(35):func(125):reason(103):.\crypto\pkcs12\p12_p8e.c:88:

Comment: @caf: looking at the last error in p12_p8e.c:88 it is failing to create the digest on: p8->digest = PKCS12_item_i2d_encrypt(pbe, ASN1_ITEM_rptr(PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO),pass, passlen, p8inf, 1);

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @caf for your help. 
By trial and error I fixed PEM_read_PrivateKey() error by adding the following to the start:

```
if (EVP_get_cipherbyname("aes-256-cbc") == NULL)
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
```

However, I'm still looking for the best (practice) way of generating the keys and then using the private key for signing. From my limited understanding, I am looking for openssl methods that adhere to RSA's "PKCS #1 v2.0: RSA Cryptography Standard"

Comment: Saved my day after hours of debugging, 12 years old answer. :D